# Problems extracting nested sections from an HTML page

Tags: java, python

Trying to extract nested sections from an html page. I want to eventually create wiki pages for each sections. Extracting the text only will not be an issue, but extracting the nested sections will be.

The page I am trying to extract sections from is - http://goo.gl/xb7Ydd

I am planning to extract the sections into an XML(or a json?) which can look something like this -

```
<1.1> Section 1.1
 <1.1.1> Subsection of 1.1 </1.1.1>
 <1.1.2> Subsection of 1.1 </1.1.2>
</1.1>
```

Can anyone suggest approaches other than complex regexs?

Comment: Use a html parser, a popular one is BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Could not prettify this page using bs4. 'maximum recursion depth exceeded'.

Comment: `soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print(soup.prettify())` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html") # get page using requests

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

s = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('\.pdf'))# find all .pdf's
print s

[u'http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.pdf', u'http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/csprd01/CMIS-v1.1-csprd01.pdf', u'http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/CMIS-v1.1.pdf']
```

Comment: Finding all pdfs / crawling is not the issue. Parsing nested sections using bs4 is an issue.

Comment: have you looked at the Beautifulsoup documentation? I provided a simple example, all you need is in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1: You can skip to Step 3 to see how I handled parsing the HTML.

I'm starting with the assumption that you haven't used an HTML parser before. Forgive me if the following comes off as patronizing or verbose; I'm just attempting to be thorough.

Before we get started, I should let you know that we're dealing with malformed HTML here (e.g., not a single `</p>` in sight), so we can't take a straight-forward approach. We're also dealing with a large file, so the going might be a little slow and error-prone.

If you choose to use Python for your project, there's a popular module called [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) that can help with the bad HTML. If we wanted to use it to capture the text from a section of your page (say, the intro), we would follow these steps:

1. Acquire the HTML
2. Find relevant tags, id's and classes
3. Write a script to extract info and load into XML

### Step 1

First, you need to look at the page's HTML. In your browser, after pulling the page up, right-click the page and hit "View page source". In the window that pops up, you should see a wall of text (over 38000 lines). Save the text to a file called "CMIS-v1.1-os.html", and place that file in your C drive's root folder (for convenience; put it somewhere else if you're not using Windows). We're gonna look through this to find what we'll need for the parser.

### Step 2

Let's try to get the text of the introduction. When I search for the first line of text ("The Content Management Interoperability Services..."), I'm taken to line 129. This is the abstract, so I move to the next instance: Line 617. This is the text I'm looking for, so now I need to find out how it's tagged in HTML.

Look back at the page in your browser (the rendered page, not the wall). This section is headed with the phrase "1 Introduction" (line 615). In the wall, it's tagged 'h2' (i.e. it's between  `<h2>` and `</h2>`. Now, 'h2' tags are pretty common in the wall, but this tag has the 'chapterHead' class, which isn't as common. Beyond that, it looks as if the header and the text is inside of a 'p' tag with the 'noindent' class. (Note: I'm typing as I go; some of this info might not be useful in whatever code we come up with, but it should help you with your ideas).

We know how to find a chapter (search for the 'chapterHead' class). Now let's find a chapter section. On the rendered page, I see "1.4 Examples". Searching the wall for the first line ("A set of request and response...") takes me to Line 878. In Line 876, I see the section's title in an 'h3' tag with the 'sectionHead' class. This strategy will also work for finding the tags that mark subsections and sub-subsections.

Ideally, each of the chapter sections would be contained in tags denoting a chapter, the  subsections would be in tags denoting a section, etc. This ideal structure could be represented like this:

- 1

  - 1.1

    - 1.1.1
    - 1.1.2
  - 1.2
  - 1.3

    - 1.3.1
- 2

  - 2.1

Unfortunately for us, that structure doesn't exist in this document. What we have is:

- 1
- 1.1
- 1.1.1
- 1.1.2
- 1.2
- 1.3
- 1.3.1
- 2
- 2.1

We'll have to go through these tags sequentially, reacting to the tags as we come upon them.

Based on what we've seen, our strategy will look like this:

- Find an 'h2' tag with the 'chapterHead' class
- Go through the `<p>`s that we find, keeping an eye out for 'h3', 'h4', and 'h5' tags
- Store text until we come across another 'h2' tag.

### Step 3

If you don't have Python installed, I'd go [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and download Python 3.x. Once that's done, open up a command console and execute the following:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Now, run `python` in the console. Whatever we do next can either be typed line-by-line into the console or stored in a .py file and run later.

To get set up:

```
import bs4
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring

# Change the path if you're not using Windows
with open('C:\CMIS-v1.1-os.html') as f:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f.read())
```

The first two lines import the modules we'll need. The last two lines just read the contents of your HTML file into a `BeautifulSoup` class. `soup` has a lot of methods that make searching for tags and classes easy. These lines might take a while to execute because your file is so large.

```
first_chapter = soup.find('h2', class_='chapterHead')
```

`first_chapter` holds the first 'h2' tags and its contents. Since this tag is on the same level as the other chapters, sections, and subsections, we'll use it as a starting point.

```
siblings = first_chapter.next_siblings
element = next(siblings)
```

`siblings` is a generator that'll deliver the contents of the document to us piecemeal. If you type `print(element)` in the console, you should see the text that follows the 'h2' tag (i.e., the first paragraph of the introduction). Ideally, this text would be inside a 'p' tag, but we're not dealing with well-formed HTML.

Every time that you run `element = next(siblings)`, the generator delivers the element that follows on the same level of the document tree (it won't deliver any embedded tags). If we want to know the name of the tag, we can get it with `element.name`; if the element is text or a comment tag, it'll have no name.

Now, in order to build XML, we'll use `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

```
intro = Element('1')
intro.text = element
sect1 = SubElement(intro, '1.1')
print(tostring(intro))
intro.remove(sect1)
```

If you type `tostring(intro)` into your console, you should see some nice-looking XML. We'll remove `sect1` for now.

Lastly, we need a way to track the level of text that we're on as we iterate through `siblings`. From what I saw of your page, subsections go up to four levels below the chapter level. Let's set up some control structure that checks the names of tags in order to determine what level we're at (this is meant for inspirational purposes):

```
depth = {'h2': 1, 'h3': 2,  'h4': 3, 'h5': 4, 'h6': 5}
depth_tags = ['h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']
level = [1]
sects = [intro]
xml_tag = ''
last_sect = intro

for element in siblings:
    old_depth = len(level)
    tag = element.name
    if tag == 'h2':
        break
    if tag in depth_tags:
        if old_depth < depth[tag]:
            level.append(1)
        else:
            level = level[0:depth[tag]]
            level[-1] += 1
            sects = sects[0:depth[tag]-1]
        last_sect = sects[-1]
        xml_tag = '.'.join(level)
        sects.append(SubElement(last_sect, xml_tag))
    sect = sect[-1]
    if tag == 'p':
        sect.text = element.text
```

I'll explain the logic:

- Initialize useful variables:

  1. `depth` for converting a header tag to a depth level (assuming that the headers correspond exactly to a subsection type; if this assumption is wrong, you might try checking the element's class using `element.get('class')`).
  2. `depth_tags` for storing the tags that signify a change in depth (excluding 'h2' because we're only doing the introduction).
  3. `level` for keeping track of the current depth level.
  4. `sects` for keeping track of the current XML node to which we may add text.
  5. `xml_tag` for storing the label of the current XML node.
  6. `last_sect` for storing the parent of the current XML node.
- Iterate through all of the elements, starting with the element after the first paragraph (which we captured earlier in code).

  1. If the next element is named 'h2', we know that we've reached the end of the current chapter, so we'll call it quits.
  2. If the next element is one of the `depth_tags`, we'll change the XML node appropriately:

     - If the element's level is lower than the previous element's level (we're going deeper into the tree), we'll add a '1' to our `level` list (so if the list was `[1, 1]` before, it'll now be `[1, 1, 1]`).
     - If the element's level is the same or higher than the previous element's level (we're going sideways or higher into the tree), we'll shorten our `level` list to the length corresponding to our level; we'll also increment the last number of the updated list. (Example: the last tag was 'h5', and the current tag is 'h3'. If the `level` list was `[1, 1, 3, 2]` before, it'll now be `[1, 2]`.) We'll also shorten the `sects` list to make room for a new XML node.
     - We'll add a new XML node to the `sects` list. `'.'.join(level)` turns `[1, 2, 3]` into "1.2.3".
  3. If the next element is a 'p' tag, we'll write its contents into the current XML node.

I haven't tested this, but even if it works perfectly, I'm certain you'll need to be careful with handling text outside of 'p' tags (like the first paragraph we found).

### Closing Thoughts

I've gone over the basics of what you can use to get your (truly ugly-looking) HTML turned into XML. Some other points I didn't cover:

- There are many comment tags in the HTML. These are represented in BeautifulSoup as elements with no name but text content.
- You'll probably notice a lot of 'span' and 'a' tags in an `element`. Using `element.text` will make them go away, which is useful for just getting the text. If you want to leave them in, try `''.join(str(t) for t in element.contents)`.
- Just so you know, the characters 'fi' (two characters) show up as 'ﬁ' (one character) in your page. Just sayin'.